# proof that a vector-valued function is lipschitz continuous on a closed rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, vectors

This is a text in my book:

[image]

The problem is that I have never seen a mean value theorem for **vector-valued functions**. I have seen it for **functions of several varaibles**, but then it must be a **real function**, **not a vector function**.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to see their statement follow easy from a mean-value theorem?
2. I wanted to prove their statement using only the mean value theorem for functions of several varaibles, is this proof correct?:

We have as in the text the function $\textbf{f}(\textbf{x},t)$.

For each component we have that $|\textbf{f}_i(\textbf{x}_1,t)|-\textbf{f}_i(\textbf{x}_2,t)|\le |\nabla_M|*|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|$. **When they say continuous differentiable components, it means that their partial derivatives are continuous, hence the gradient has a maximum value $|\nabla_M|$ on the closed set?**

And now since:

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2...+k^2}\le |a|+|b|...+|k|$, we get that

$|\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}_1,t)-\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}_2,t)|\le N*|\nabla_M|*|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|$, where N is the number of components.

Is this proof correct?

It became 3 questions, because I would also very much like someone to confirm what I wrote in bold text in question 2?

PS: I also actually used cauchy schwarz like this:

$|\textbf{f}_i(\textbf{x}_1,t)|-\textbf{f}_i(\textbf{x}_2,t)|=\nabla_{f_i}(c)\cdot|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|\le_{CS}|\nabla_{f_i}(c)|*|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|\le |\nabla_M|*|\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{x}_2|$

I used * for multiplying and $\cdot$ for dot-product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. This is a very short answer, but there is little more I can add to your work.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read through it. Have you personally ever seen a mean value theorem for vector valued functions that can be used in this case? Also is there another way to interpret "continuously differentiable components"?

Comment: The inequality that you have proved is sometimes called _The theorem of finte increments_, although this name is also used sometimes for the mean value theorem. You can't have a mean value theorem for vector valued functions (the $c$ for each component will be different), but you can have an inequality.

Comment: Thanks!, and do you agree that when they say continuously differentiable components, they mean that the partial derivatives are continuous, there isn't another way to understand that?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!